# [PHP-JQuery]: check if a form entry alreay exists in database without clicking on submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am developing a form in a web page where a user is supposed to write the tax code of a person and I would like the system to automatically checks the database if a person with that inserted tax code already exists BEFORE clicking on the submit button. Here's some jquery code of my php page:

```
jQuery("#form1").validate({
    rules: {
        name: "required",
        surname: "required",
        ...

        <?php
            echo '

            tax_code:{
                remote: {
                    url: "check_cf.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {
                        tax_code: function() {
                                    return jQuery( "#tax_code" ).val();
                                }
                        }
                }
            },

            ';
        ?>
    },

    messages: {
        name: "Insert client's name!",
        ... ,
        <?php

        echo '

            tax_code: {
                remote: "You have already inserted a person with that tax code",
            }

        ';

        ?>

    }
});
```

and here is check_cf.php

```
<?php
  $deep="";
  include($deep."include/head.php");
  $cfpost=$_POST['tax_code'];
  $cliente_cf=$sistema->clienti->allClienti(" where codice_fiscale='".$cfpost."'  ");
  //echo $usernamepost;


  if(isset($cliente_cf[0]["id"])) echo json_encode(false);
  else echo json_encode(true); 
?>
```

and nothing works...I don't know where I am making a mistake.
Thanks to all

Comment: you can do this by ajax run use ajax on form submit.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what you're talking about...I'm just a trainee and I have never programmed in front-end with js/jquery... I think I would need an example